# Camera and saving image in SQL database

Tags: android

I want to open Camera onclick. It's working fine. Now after taking picture I don't want to save that picture in gallery. I want to save that Picture in sql database

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to store the whole picture in the database and not its path ?

Comment: I want to store some other values like place where it is taken,friends in that picture.etc.And no its not complsury to save whole picture in database.I can store it in gallery but Then i have to create A seprate folder in gallery

Comment: I've put snippets of the answer, hope they help, but i still think the best solution is to create a folder in gallery and put the path in the DB

Comment: @user1950815 : Assuming you will be using the built-in SQLite capabilities, I would recommend *against* storing the whole image in a database. I agree with Dany Y in that you should save the images to either internal or external storage and simply put the path of the image file into the database. If you don't want the images to appear in the stock Gallery app then create an empty file called `.nomedia` in the folder where you store them.

Answer (score 0):

To insert an image in the DB, write this code :

```
public class CameraHandler implements PictureCallback {
.....
 @Override
 public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
       insertImageInDB(data);
}

public void insertImageInDB(byte[] theImageBytes){
    SQLiteDatabase db               =   dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql                      =   "INSERT INTO MY_IMAGES (image_id,other_data,the_image) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    SQLiteStatement insertStmt      =   db.compileStatement(sql);
    insertStmt.bindString(1, id);
    insertStmt.bindString(2,otherData);
    insertStmt.bindBlob(3, theImageBytes);
    insertStmt.executeInsert();
    db.close();
}

}
```